How to fill "List Price with Tax for Display" with XML Feeds from Amazon sp-api?
I'm trying to list items on amazon with the sp-api and feeds.
I'm currently using:

POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA
POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA
POST_PRODUCT_DATA
POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA

And I'm trying to complete an item on AmazonSellerCenter.
I registered all the required informations, expect one "List Price with Tax for Display" and I dont understand how to fill it.
I tried: "TaxStandardPrice", "MAP", "MSRPWithTax", "BusinessPrice" and "StandardPrice" (but the last one is for the "Your Price" Input)
<MessageType>Price</MessageType>
<Message>
  <MessageID>1</MessageID>
  <Price>
    <SKU>123456789</SKU>
    <StandardPrice currency="EUR">199</StandardPrice>
    <MAP currency="EUR">200</MAP>
    <TaxStandardPrice>201</TaxStandardPrice>
  </Price>
</Message>

Does someone know what I'm missing ?

I cannot remember exactly, since XML feeds like POST_PRODUCT_DATA are deprecated and will be removed by Amazon very soon, but that field should be either the MSRP or the MSRPWithTax inside the DescriptionData container.
Please be advised that, due to a recent communication by Amazon, MSRPWithTax is not required if you send products using XML. Remember also that a value of 0 is supported if you don't have a List Price to provide.

MSRPWithTax can not be in DescriptionData. I'm talking with the Amazon support at the same time and they said this is MSRPWithTax too but even in pricing there is no error but no change in the offer.

You can see that MSRPWithTax is inside the DescriptionData by checking the Product.XSD here: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/Product.xsd
